# Dativ von "alles"?

Tags: grammatical-case, pronoun, dative

> I am afraid that I would expose her to everything,

Wäre es richtig, so zu übersetzen?

> Ich habe Angst, dass ich sie alles aussetzen würde.

Das Verb "aussetzen" braucht einen Dativ, aber wenn es um "alles" geht, sollte es einfach so bleiben?

Comment: Entweder "Ich habe Angst, etwas zu tun" oder "Ich habe Angst davor, dass ... (etwas passiert)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ich habe Angst, sie allem (oder all dem ...) auszusetzen"